# Keep Jquery slideDown menu open when hovering over that menu?

Tags: jquery

having some difficulties with my Jquery slideDown menu. It works perfectly when I hover over the button that triggers the slideDown event, but when I hover over the sub-menu that slid down, it triggers the slideUp event and closes the menu.

I'm looking for a way to alter my code to say that after I hover over the initial button to trigger the sub-menu slideDown, that sub-menu stays open if I'm hovering on the sub-menu until I am no longer hovering on the initial button *or* the sub-menu.. I hope that's clear enough.

Here's the Jquery I have so far, which works fine except for the sub-menu!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var menu = $('.menu')

menu.hide();

$('#mainbutton').hover(

    function () {
        $('.menu').stop(true, true).slideDown(400);
    },

    function () {
        $('.menu').stop(true, true).slideUp(400);
    }

);

});
```

Any suggestions? I'm sure it's something pretty easy, I've just not been able to phrase my question correctly enough to find someone else's solution u_u

Thanks for any help you may provide!

edit: here's the jsfiddle -- http://jsfiddle.net/mXXEP/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a particularly easy problem to solve (out of the box) as there are multiple elements that rely on each other's state to work properly. I have done this before with setTimeout.

Use [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) to maintain control of a variable that tells each of the hover events what to do. Just threw a jsFiddle together that does what you want (though I think there's a problem with the slideup part at the mo):

http://jsfiddle.net/3vL3a/

And the JS / HTML:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var menu = $('.menu')
    var timeout = 0;
    var hovering = false;
    menu.hide();

    $('#mainbutton')
        .on("mouseenter", function () {
        hovering = true;
        // Open the menu
        $('.menu')
            .stop(true, true)
            .slideDown(400);

        if (timeout > 0) {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
        }
    })
        .on("mouseleave", function () {
        resetHover();
    });

    $(".menu")
        .on("mouseenter", function () {
        // reset flag
        hovering = true;
        // reset timeout
        startTimeout();
    })
        .on("mouseleave", function () {
        // The timeout is needed incase you go back to the main menu
        resetHover();
    });

    function startTimeout() {
        // This method gives you 1 second to get your mouse to the sub-menu
        timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            closeMenu();
        }, 1000);
    };

    function closeMenu() {
        // Only close if not hovering
        if (!hovering) {
            $('.menu').stop(true, true).slideUp(400);
        }
    };

    function resetHover() {
        // Allow the menu to close if the flag isn't set by another event
        hovering = false;
        // Set the timeout
        startTimeout();
    };
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="mainbutton">Hover over me!</div>
<div class="menu" style="background-color:red;">Test menu text
    <br/>Test menu text
    <br/>Test menu text
    <br/>Test menu text
    <br/>Test menu text
    <br/>
</div>
```

Comment: There's a small issue where if I go to the main button and then through the submenu quickly it just jumps back up instead of sliding, however. gonna try to fix myself, thanks again

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that... it really won't take much to fix either :)

Comment: What would i need to do to fix that issue?

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to do this is to just check if mouseleave the `.menu div`, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var menu = $('.menu')
menu.hide();

$('#mainbutton').mouseover(
    function () {
        menu.stop(true, true).slideDown(400);
    }
);

$(".menu").mouseleave(       
    function () {
        menu.stop(true, true).slideUp(400)
    })
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mXXEP/3/)

Comment: This doesn't really act as a menu - it doesn't disappear when you mouse-off the main button (unless you mouse-off from the sub-menu).

Comment: I fixed it by adding a function where if the mouse enters the div underneath it then it also slides up :-)

Comment: This helped my drop down menu from continuously bouncing when hovering over the submenus. NICE!