# Jquery slideDown menu when hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

Okay so I've been trying to make a navigation that will have a box sliding down when hovered, and I found this: [Keep Jquery slideDown menu open when hovering over that menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18396857/keep-jquery-slidedown-menu-open-when-hovering-over-that-menu)

The third answer almost worked for me, but my problem is, when I hover the main menu, the submenu will also slide down, and when I hover the submenu, nothing will happen.

I'm not sure if this is would possible, but I'd like to make a navigation that will slide down only the one that I hover on.

This is my code so far. I really suck at this, I don't know Jquery, so if you could help me, please do. Thank you so much!

**Jquery**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var menu = $('.menu')

    menu.hide();

    $('#mainbutton').mouseover(

        function () {
            menu.stop(true, true).slideDown(400);
        }
    );

    $(".menu").mouseleave(

        function () {
            menu.stop(true, true).slideUp(400)
        })

});
```

**CSS**

```
        #navigation {
    border: solid 1px black;
    height: 300px;
}

.mainbutton {
    margin-top: 10px;
    -webkit-order: 2;
    margin-right: 0%;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.dropdown {
    -webkit-order: 3;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 2px dotted #f1f1f1;
    width: 195px;
    height: auto;
    text-align: justify;
    background: url('http://www.polyvore.com/cgi/img-thing?.out=jpg&size=l&tid=25977922');
}

.menu {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    padding-left: 8%;
}

.menu a, a:visited {
    font-family: Abstrec, sans-serif;
    color: #505050;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: .5em;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #dbdbdb;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.menu a:hover {
    color: #bfbfbf;
    -webkit-transition:.3s;
    transition:.3s;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #aef4e7;
}

.itemone {
    -webkit-order: 1;
    height: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    z-index: 3;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

**HTML**

```
        <div class="navigation">
        <div class="nav">

                <div id="mainbutton">
                   <center> <a href="#">about</a> </center>
                </div> </div> </div>


        <div class="dropdown">

            <div class="menu">
                <div id="itemone"></div>

this is a sample text
this is a sample text
this is a sample text
this is a sample text
this is a sample text

    <br></div></div>


        <div class="navigation">
        <div class="nav">

                <div id="mainbutton">
                   <center> <a href="#">tagboard</a> </center>
                </div> </div> </div>


        <div class="dropdown">

            <div class="menu">
                <div id="itemone"></div>

this is a sample text
this is a sample text
this is a sample text
this is a sample text
this is a sample text

    <br></div></div>
```

PS: jsfiddle wont let me generate. i don't know why so sorry if it's a mess up.

Anyway if you'd like to see it then here: http://sdmkn.blogspot.com/

Thank you so much!!

Comment: This may be sound crazy but....why are you using JQuery? Why not Pure CSS?

Comment: @LOTUSMS i have no idea how to do that in pure css sorry.

Comment: No problem. I see you have your answer already. But it is rather easy.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's an example <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/KS4VV/)**</kbd>

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1
      <ul>
        <li>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi ut tortor vel mi elementum consequat eu quis velit. Vestibulum nec bibendum lacus, sit amet tristique nulla.
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Item 2
      <ul>
        <li>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi ut tortor vel mi elementum consequat eu quis velit. Vestibulum nec bibendum lacus, sit amet tristique nulla.
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

---

```
nav {
  width: 250px;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  background: #ddd;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  padding: 2px 0;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
li ul {
display: none;
}
li ul li {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

---

```
(function($) {
  $('ul li').mouseover(function() {
    $('ul',this).stop().slideDown(400, 'linear');
  });
  $('li, li ul').mouseout(function() {
    $('li ul').stop().slideUp(400, 'linear');
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: For a moment, it wouldn't align with the rest of the elements on my sidebar, but I just had to make some adjustments, and it is now working perfectly fine. Thank you so much!